# FedEx Shipping Codes

Tags: shopify, fedex

I am looking for the list of codes that are associated with different FedEx Shipping Methods.

Here is the run down of what we are doing. We have a Web Hook setup up to forward all of our orders to a portal that organizes the orders and sends the orders to a 3PL at our fulfillment center. We want to start forwarding out the proper shipping methods also which we need to assign to numbers. So the code that is sent through the web hook to our portal for each different shipping method is needed. Sorry if I am off on wording, I am not the tech guy over here haha.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here's the list of valid codes:

```
PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT
PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY
FEDEX_2_DAY
FEDEX_2_DAY_SATURDAY_DELIVERY
STANDARD_OVERNIGHT
FIRST_OVERNIGHT
FIRST_OVERNIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY
FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER
FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY
FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY
FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT_SATURDAY_DELIVERY
INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY
INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_SATURDAY_DELIVERY
INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY
INTERNATIONAL_FIRST
INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_FREIGHT
INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_FREIGHT
GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY
FEDEX_GROUND
INTERNATIONAL_GROUND
```

Sourced from FedEx docs: http://www.fedex.com/us/solutions/wis/pdf/xml_transguide.pdf?link=4

I've added this list to the [Shopify Wiki](http://wiki.shopify.com/FedEx_Shipping_Codes) too.

Comment: I believe the codes outputted have an underscore in them in areas where there should be a space. Example: FedEx Express Saver= "FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER". At least this is what we pulled from the orders that have been pushed through our system. Can you confirm this on the rest of them? Thank you David!

Comment: @user1566350 You’re right. We’ve updated the [wiki](http://wiki.shopify.com/FedEx_Shipping_Codes) and I’ll update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the values your 3PL expects may not be the true "carrier" values so there is no way to provide you with such a list.

These are the values that FedEx expects for Web Services which is the current list. The XML API has been retired and did not support all services.

```
FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_2_DAY
FEDEX_2_DAY_AM
FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT
FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER
FEDEX_FREIGHT_ECONOMY
FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY
FEDEX_GROUND
FIRST_OVERNIGHT
GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY
INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY
INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_FREIGHT
INTERNATIONAL_FIRST
INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY
INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY_FREIGHT
PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT
SMART_POST
STANDARD_OVERNIGHT
```